# Can't execute servlet from .html page

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

The servlet loads fine in Tomcat. Right now I can access my prototype .html page just fine, but when I click the button to execute the servlet, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class dbServlet

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class dbServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class dbServlet
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dbServlet
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Below is the code for my prototype servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class databaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text.html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println("<xml version = \"1.0\"?>");
out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD " +
"XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org" +
"/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">");
out.println("<html xmlns = \"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">");

out.println("<head>");
out.println("<title>MySQL Servlet</title>");
out.println("<style type='text/css'>");
out.println("body{background-color: blue}");
out.println("</style>");
out.println("</head>");

out.println("<body>");
out.println("<h1>The MySQL Servlet Works!</h1>");
out.println("</body>");

out.println("</html>");
out.close();
}
}
```

Does anyone know what that stacktrace could mean?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dbServlet
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)

From above stack trace:

Your servlet is `databaseServlet` but you are calling `dbServlet`. It seems you have wrong entry in `web.xml`

NOTE: By the way java naming convention suggests that class name starts with Capital letter.

Comment: I actually found this today, and you were absolutely right. Thank you!

Comment: @user1652842: Glad it helped you. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You have not included Servlet mapping in the question.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dbServlet
```

You have a Servlet named `databaseServlet` and You have declared `dbServlet` in the deployment descriptor.

Your Servlet entry should go something like this.

Example:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DatabaseServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.DatabaseServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DatabaseServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dbServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Unrelated to the question:

Try to use MVC pattern where you can JSP for presentation, Servlets as controller to redirect web application's flow and Modle as entities.